# centos 6 nfs: logs not showing anywhere

Tags: centos, nfs

Can someone please tell me where NFS logs in centos 6? Or perhaps where I can tell NFS to send logs?

At the present time, there appears to be no such setting. Trying to get the thing to work without logs is quite frustrating.

---

```
[root@houston netshare]# locate nfs| grep log
[root@houston netshare]# 
[root@houston netshare]# grep -Rni "nfs" /var/log
/var/log/anaconda.storage.log:23:20:41:33,962 DEBUG   : registered device format class NFS as nfs
/var/log/anaconda.storage.log:24:20:41:33,962 DEBUG   : registered device format class NFSv4 as nfs4
```

This is a day-old centos 6 install from livecd and yum update has been run.

---

```
[root@houston ~]# cat /etc/exports 
/var/netshare   10.10.0.10(rw,sync,no_root_squash)
/var/netshare/esxi1 192.168.111.119(rw,sync,no_root_squash)
/var/netshare 192.168.111.101(rw,sync.no_root_squash)


[root@houston ~]# chkconfig --list | egrep '(nfs|rpc*)'

nfs             0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
nfslock         0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
rpcbind         0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
rpcgssd         0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
rpcidmapd       0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
rpcsvcgssd      0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off



[root@houston ~]# ps aux | egrep '(nfs|rpc*)'
rpc       1482  0.0  0.0  18972  1012 ?        Ss   Dec06   0:00 rpcbind
root      1587  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec06   0:00 [fc_rport_eq]
rpcuser   1648  0.0  0.0  23344  1352 ?        Ss   Dec06   0:00 rpc.statd
root      1690  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec06   0:00 [rpciod/0]
root      1691  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec06   0:00 [rpciod/1]
root      1692  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec06   0:00 [rpciod/2]
root      1693  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec06   0:00 [rpciod/3]
root     29056  0.0  0.0 107304   280 ?        Ss   11:36   0:00 rpc.rquotad
root     29060  0.0  0.0  21760  1264 ?        Ss   11:36   0:00 rpc.mountd
root     29111  0.0  0.0  25160   760 ?        Ss   11:36   0:00 rpc.idmapd
root     29116  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:36   0:00 [nfsd4]
root     29117  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:36   0:00 [nfsd4_callbacks]
root     29118  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:36   0:00 [nfsd]
root     29119  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:36   0:00 [nfsd]
root     29120  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:36   0:00 [nfsd]
root     29121  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:36   0:00 [nfsd]
root     29122  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:36   0:00 [nfsd]
root     29123  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:36   0:00 [nfsd]
root     29124  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:36   0:00 [nfsd]
root     29125  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:36   0:00 [nfsd]
root     29357  0.0  0.0 100992   748 pts/1    S+   12:56   0:00 egrep (nfs|rpc*)


[root@houston ~]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             loopback/8          reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:https 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:51414 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW udp dpt:sunrpc 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:sunrpc 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:nfs 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:32803 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW udp dpt:filenet-rpc 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:892 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:47649 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW udp dpt:892 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:rquotad 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW udp dpt:rquotad 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:pftp 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW udp dpt:pftp 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 5/min burst 5 LOG level debug prefix `iptables denied: ' 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Comment: Do you have a firewall enabled? Have you tried this with and without iptables?

Comment: Yes I have the firewall on. Updated the question with iptables -L. Reminder: this question isn't "how do I use nfs?" it's "where are the nfs logs?"

Comment: Yeah, but we don't know that until you demonstrate that you do know through including all the relevant information in the question. We're trained to see past the 'XY Problem'.

Comment: @Adrian fair enough.

Comment: BTW, you seen this page? http://wiki.linux-nfs.org/wiki/index.php/General_troubleshooting_recommendations

Comment: No, hadn't seen it. But it doesn't help my situation; I still don't know where to look for failures because I don't know where NFS is logging. NFS is running and I can mount folders from remote machines fine. I'm having an issue creating a datastore within esxi and want the NFS logs to help narrow the issue. Although, it does mention trace debugging so I'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: What are the permissions on `/var/netshare`? Type `ls -ld /var/netshare`.

Comment: @ancillary Yeah, strace is my friend and yours too. If I can't figure out what in tarnation is going on, I strace it and dig through the output.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've just had the same problem in 2016, using CentOS 6.5 on my workstation, and CentOS 7 on the client (a Vagrant box on the same host).  My specific problem was the same as the OP's, I couldn't find any nfsd logging.

### Use *rpcdebug* to Enable NFS Logging

The answer for me, for anyone else coming to this question in the future, was to use the command (as root/sudo on the server end):

```
rpcdebug -m nfsd all
```

to turn on full debugging to `/var/log/messages`

This will enable the kind of output shown in **ewwhite**'s post above when you issue the mount command from the client.

to turn off again, use

```
rpcdebug -m nfsd -c all
```

you can reduce the amount of debug info by replacing the keyword 'all' with a specific module.  These are listed in

```
man rpcdebug
```

### Add Startup Flags to rpc.mountd and rpc.idmapd to Increase Debug

You can get more debug info by adding `-d all` to rpc.mountd and `-vvv` to rpc.idmapd.

Do this by editing `/etc/sysconfig/nfs' and setting:

```
...
RPCMOUNTDOPTS=" -d all"
...
RPCIDMAPDARGS="-vvv"
...
```

You will need to restart the nfs service (as root/sudo) for this to apply:

```
service nfs restart
```

This is the CentOS 6.n approach.  Under CentOS 7 you would need to look at `systemctl restart [servicename]` instead.  [servicename] may well be nfs but I haven't done this under CentOS 7 yet.

For clarity, these debug log messages will be written to `/var/log/messages`.

Comment: "rpcdebug - nfsd -c all" returns "unknown module nsfd". NFS server is running.

Comment: Hi @MarkusBawidamann, I think you have left the m out of rpcdebug -m nfsd all, assuming your comment is a direct cut and paste?

Comment: Apologies if that reply was too simple - I no longer use CentOS on my workstation (moved to Ubuntu a couple of years back), and don't have a platform to look into this further.

Answer (score 2):

Did you look in `/var/log/messages`? NFS logs there.

```
Dec  7 08:36:25 OGC_Mirror kernel: RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
Dec  7 08:36:25 OGC_Mirror kernel: RPC: Registered udp transport module.
Dec  7 08:36:25 OGC_Mirror kernel: RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
Dec  7 08:36:25 OGC_Mirror kernel: RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
Dec  7 08:36:25 OGC_Mirror kernel: Installing knfsd (copyright (C) 1996 okir@monad.swb.de).
Dec  7 08:36:25 OGC_Mirror rpc.mountd[2459]: Version 1.2.3 starting
Dec  7 08:36:25 OGC_Mirror kernel: NFSD: Using /var/lib/nfs/v4recovery as the NFSv4 state recovery directory
Dec  7 08:36:25 OGC_Mirror kernel: NFSD: starting 90-second grace period
```

Comment: Sure did. grep -Rni "nfs" /var/log returns diddly. A couple of lines about anaconda...and I _know_ there should be more logs because I'm failing to mount.

Comment: Failure to mount can have many causes, one of which is NFS not running on the server.  That would certainly explain absence of log entries.  Can you be sure the NFS service is running, and accessible?

Comment: It is. `rpcinfo -p` returns correctly from client. And I also managed to get the client to mount the folder, but the questions still stands-it'd be nice to have those logs.

Comment: @ancillary and you need may need the `portreserve` service running. Is this the NFS client or the server?

Comment: This is the server; NFS is running and I am able to mount remotely. I want those logs though.

Comment: What logs are you expecting to see?

Comment: @ewwhite permissions errors, mount errors; I don't know. Something telling me why a remote machine is giving me a permission denied, or unable to mount status.

Comment: Please edit your original question with the output of `/etc/exports` from the NFS server and `chkconfig --list | egrep '(nfs|rpc*)'`.

Comment: Change the permissions on the mountpoint to allow ESXi's anonymous NFS mounting. E.g. `chmod 777 /var/netshare`

Comment: @ewwhite thanks... but the issue turned out to be that esxi was using some odd port that wasn't mentioned anywhere else (50538) for nfs.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest checking `/var/log/` first, as logs usaually go under that somewhere.

You could also check the configuration files for where the logs are being stored.

`/var/nfs/nfslog` should have the actual NFS transaction log records, if that's what you're looking for, and you should be able to find the rest of your log configurations in `/etc/nfs/nfslog.conf` and `/etc/default/nfslogd`.

Comment: `[root@houston netshare]# locate nfs| grep log \
[root@houston netshare]# `. grepping /var/log returns nil. Think there might be something missing? This is a brand new centos box from live cd & yum update

Comment: You opened up the ports for NFS, right?