# Cannot find NFS server logs on CentOS 6.5

Tags: centos6, nfs

I cannot find the logs for a NFS server on a CentOS 6.5 machine. `grep -Rni "nfs" /var/log/messages` returns nothing useful.

The NFS service is running and I am able to mount the NFS share from most of my other client machines, I just need to see the logs as one of the client machines is failing to mount the NFS share.

Answer (score 2):

I've just had the same problem in 2016, using CentOS 6.5 on my workstation, and CentOS 7 on the client (a Vagrant box on the same host).  My specific problem was the same as the OP's, I couldn't find any nfsd logging.

### Use *rpcdebug* to Enable NFS Logging

The answer for me, for anyone else coming to this question in the future, was to use the command (as root/sudo on the server end):

```
rpcdebug -m nfsd all
```

to turn on full debugging to `/var/log/messages`

I've put a more complete answer against the question [centos 6 nfs: logs not showing anywhere](https://serverfault.com/questions/456112/centos-6-nfs-logs-not-showing-anywhere/772373#772373), which addresses the same issue.

I also used **MadHatter**'s suggestion (Kudos) of `-d all` on `rpc.mountd` and explain how I did this in the longer post.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the NFS service doesn't normally log (not least because modern Linuces handle much of NFS in the kernel).  If you're trying to chase down a mount issue, you could try restarting `rpc.mountd` (which handles such things) with the `-d all` flag, and see if that increases verbosity.  I'm guessing it would continue to log where it already was, so keep an eye on `/var/log/messages`.

Comment: I cannot see the `rpc.mountd` service in `/etc/init.d/` ... all I can see is `rpcbind     rpcgssd     rpcidmapd   rpcsvcgssd`

Comment: How about in `/etc/init.d/nfs`?

Comment: Yes, this is present. So what will be the complete command? `/etc/init.d/nfs -d all` ?

Comment: No.  You will need to get into it and either edit the line that starts `mountd` to add that flag, or you get it into the `$RPCMOUNTDOPTS` variable.  Don't forget to keep a copy before you start editing, in case you need to revert.

Comment: ok, just to clarify further, the line `[ -x /usr/sbin/rpc.mountd ] || exit 5` should be replaced by `[ -x /usr/sbin/rpc.mountd -d all] || exit 5` ???

Comment: No.  That line merely tests if the binary exists and is executable (`-x`) before proceeding.  Adding the flag as you show above would probably render the script syntactically invalid, resulting in an error.  You probably shouldn't be doing this if you don't have experience in `bash` scripting; you may wish instead to consult your system administrator.

Comment: Unfortunately I am the sys admin :). I found the correct line (I think) ...

`echo -n $"Starting NFS mountd: "
        daemon rpc.mountd -d all $RPCMOUNTDOPTS`

But I cannot see any new logs appearing in /var/log/messages

Comment: If that flag is indeed causing mountd to log, where those logs go is entirely subject to `/etc/rsyslog.conf` and associated files.  You may need to ensure that mountd output is properly logged before you can see it.  Please don't take this too hard, but it is possible that you should also get your employer to send you on some training courses before giving you any more sysadmin responsibilities.

Comment: I cannot see any mention of `nfs` or `mountd` in `rsyslog.conf`. I am self employed and not as a sys admin thankfully :) ... and this NFS thing is for a proprietary old software that requires it. This NFS logging looks to be quite complex, I don't know why as usually Linux stuff is pretty straight forward and logical and I just need to see a log file. Anyways, the software also supports CIFS, so looks like I will try that now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: NFS and mountd both, to the extent that they log at all, most likely log under the `kernel` facility.